# Access the GPS and camera in the browser in both windows mobile, IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, mobile, camera, windows-mobile

I have to write an app that basically takes photographs, apply some filters (like Instagram) and then upload it through HTTP or FTP along with the GPS coordinate of where the photo was taken.

Since I will have to write this for Windows Mobile, IOS and Android: is there a way to do this in the browser (access the camera and GPS) in a way that it will work for Windows Mobile, IOS and Android?

If the answer is no, there is no way to do this in the browser then: is there a framework/api/anything that I could use to do the job? (camera, GPS and send things over the internet).

I just want to avoid re-write the same code for three different Operational Systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you could achieve those requirmetns using HTML5: for example:

controlling the camera:

http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

or gatting location:

[enter link description here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nagavo/archive/2011/11/29/html-5-how-to-track-your-location-using-the-geolocation-api.aspx)

and then as you already mentioned you could export this web application using PhoneGap to 
act as a Native application.

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows phone < 8 do not have IE10, which means, no webcam. http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2943792-provide-ie-10-on-wp-7-8

Comment: Not even the last chrome for android can access the camera

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no you won't be able to do this from the browser.

That said, some part can be used one 3 systems :

write an application that already have a picture and some GPS coords and upload it through http request with some GPS data.

but you will have to write native code to get the picture from the camera and to get GPS coordinates on each system, I don't know other solution and would be glad to read something more interresting here.

Comment: Seems like phoneGap should be able to run those actions on some mobile platforms, see its description here : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is possible to write the same code and get it compiled to many different mobile platforms. The answer is [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/app/).